# Google Form output to remote MySQL database

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

I have a Google Form I created.  I have a website with a remote MySQL database.  I would like to embed the Google Form into my site (this I've figured out), however instead of the data from form submission being stored in a Google Spreadsheet(s), I'd like the data to be sent to my MySQL database, to a predefined table designed to accept the data types being collected and validated for in the Google Form.

I have researched and come across Google Apps Scripts (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc).  My issue is that I'm not experienced with Google Apps Scripts and am seeking guidance in setting this up.  I have the Google Form, access to a my Google Apps account, and the connection string to my remote MySQL database with administrator privileges.  I'm seeking guidance, step-by-step as I have not found any tutorials online yet.  If you can guide me to a tutorial, that would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2):

Recently you can use a database in Google app script.
App script support (  Google Cloud SQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle databases ) with JDBC Class

DOcumentation : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

You can add script in Google From.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create a form that does not send responses to a linked spreadsheet.  In the "RESPONSE" menu, choose "CHOOSE RESPONSE DESTINATION".  You can create an installable 'Form Submit' trigger to run some code.  In the code editor, choose RESOURCES, CURRENT PROJECT TRIGGERS,  add a trigger, and set it to run when the form is submitted.   Then you'll need to use get item responses:

[Google documentation - Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getItemResponses())

Answer (score 0):

Bruce McPherson offers some [step-by-step guides on his site](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/dbabstraction/driverdbabstraction) if you use his cDbAbstraction library to access any external DBs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to roll your own solution to this, check out the Form integration in [SeekWell](https://www.notion.so/seekwell/Google-Forms-Addon-bf2891ec6e7c4dd9b977c31e2ab73747). You just write a SQL snippet and can map fields in the Form to parameters in the SQL.

Disclaimer: I made this.